# SQL column duplicate value count

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a `Student` table. Currently it has many columns like `ID`, `StudentName`, `FatherName`, `NIC`, `MotherName`, `No_Of_Childrens`, `Occupation` etc.

I want to check the `NIC` field on insert time.  If it is a duplicate, then count the duplicated `NIC` and and add the count number in `No_of_Children` column.

What is the best way to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: If you want to do it at time of insertion of data, you will have to create a trigger which will be fired if data is inserted in student table. Trigger will check if the data for NIC is duplicate and if yes then it will add count in No_of_Children column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want an UPSERT.  The most concise way to accomplish that in SQL (that I know) is through a MERGE operation.

```
declare @students table
(
  NIC int
 ,No_Of_Childrens int
);

--set up some test data to get us started
insert into @students
      select 12345,1
union select 12346,2
union select 12347,2;

--show before
select * from @students;

declare @incomingrow table(NIC int,childcount int);
insert into @incomingrow values (12345,2);

MERGE 
  --the table we want to change
  @students AS target  
USING 
  --the incoming data
  @incomingrow AS source
ON 
  --if these fields match, then the "when matched" section happens.
  --else the "when not matched".
  target.NIC = source.NIC
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  --this statement will happen when you find a match.
  --in our case, we increment the child count.
  UPDATE SET NO_OF_CHILDRENS = no_of_childrens + source.childcount
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  --this statement will happen when you do *not* find a match.
  --in our case, we insert a new row with a child count of 0.
  INSERT (nic,no_of_childrens) values(source.nic,0);

--show the results *after* the merge
select * from @students;
```

Comment: [Be careful with MERGE when existing, less problematic constructs exist](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/).